# mysql does not sort properly

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following table with entries

```
+--------------------------------------------+----------+
| menu_entry                                 | position |
+--------------------------------------------+----------+
| ADMINISTRATION::USERMANAGEMENT::USER       |        2 |
| DEMO::CHART::EXAMPLE                       |        1 |
| PROJMGMT::PROJSTRG::LOP                    |        2 |
| ADMINISTRATION::USERMANAGEMENT::RIGHTSMMGT |        1 |
| PROJMGMT::PROJSTRG::MEETINGS               |        1 |
| DEMO::GRID::CELLEDIT                       |        1 |
| DEMO::GRID::ROWEDIT                        |        3 |
| DEMO::DATAMGMT::GROUPING                   |        1 |
| DEVELOPER::APPS::ADDAPP                    |        2 |
| DEVELOPER::APPS::APPTEST                   |        1 |
| DEMO::GRID::LOCKINGDEMO                    |        4 |
| DEMO::GRID::FILTERDEMO                     |        2 |
+--------------------------------------------+----------+
```

I want to order by `menu_entry` first and second by position. I do that with the following Statement

```
 select menu_entry,position from app_names order by menu_entry, position;
```

But it only sorts by menu_entry and not by Position.
Here's the return of my statement:

```
+--------------------------------------------+----------+
| menu_entry                                 | position |
+--------------------------------------------+----------+
| ADMINISTRATION::USERMANAGEMENT::RIGHTSMMGT |        1 |
| ADMINISTRATION::USERMANAGEMENT::USER       |        2 |
| DEMO::CHART::EXAMPLE                       |        1 |
| DEMO::DATAMGMT::GROUPING                   |        1 |
| DEMO::GRID::CELLEDIT                       |        1 |
| DEMO::GRID::FILTERDEMO                     |        2 |
| DEMO::GRID::LOCKINGDEMO                    |        4 |
| DEMO::GRID::ROWEDIT                        |        3 |
| DEVELOPER::APPS::ADDAPP                    |        2 |
| DEVELOPER::APPS::APPTEST                   |        1 |
| PROJMGMT::PROJSTRG::LOP                    |        2 |
| PROJMGMT::PROJSTRG::MEETINGS               |        1 |
+--------------------------------------------+----------+
```

As you can see, DEMO::GRID::... is not sorted right.

Comment: why are you storing delimited values?

Comment: That query seems to be working as expected.

Comment: It is sorted right. `L` comes before `R`. So `LOCKINGDEMO` is before `ROWEDIT`

Comment: In fact it did its job, ordering by menu_entry... and if you had 2 menu_entry equal then it would sort by position

Comment: The query seems to work as it should? The position is only considered if there are two or more menu entries that are the same, which it isn't in your list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably order by `SUBSTRING_INDEX(menu_entry, '::', 1)` that extracts the part of the string at the left of the first `::` or by `SUBSTRING_INDEX(menu_entry, '::', 2)`, depending on what you are after:

```
select menu_entry, position
from app_names
order by
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(menu_entry, '::', 1), position;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caf0f/2).